# structure firebase functions into multiple runtimes

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I've been using firebase ecosystem for over 2 years but as it google lacks decent documentation i often come here to ask very basic things that we should learn right after "hello world".

When using firebase functions i try to modularize it to keep it readable and easy to maintain. the way i managed to do it was by having an "index" file and multiple subfiles which contains the logic for complex functions...
although it works very well, my index file is getting super long since i'm having more and more functions and it also needs to deal with some configuration for each of those specific functions...

i was messing around firebase dashboard https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/list? and i found that is possible to create a new function over this online form... when doing it the firebase backeend somehow create a new "runtime" for this function. I mean each function created by this form has its own "index.js"  "package.json"

how can i do this without need to create every function from this form?
how can i simple code a new function ecosystem, deploy it using firebase cli and have this separeted structure for it?

Answer (score 1):

All Cloud Functions are logically isolated from each other at all times at runtime.  While they might share some common code at deployment, they don't share anything else.

The Firebase CLI requires that all your functions be defined in a single entrypoint, which is your index.js.  That is just how it works.  If you don't like that, you can [deploy functions individually using gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy), but you will not be able to use the firebase-functions module to declare and implement your function.  gcloud uses different conventions.

If you want to continue to deploy with the Firebase CLI, you can add the new function to your index.js.  It can be deployed separately from your other functions using the `--only` argument.  For example, if your new function is called "fn":

```
firebase deploy --only functions:fn
```

This will deploy just fn and none of the other functions defined in your index.  You can read about this and more options in the [Firebase CLI documentation for deploying functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#deploy_specific_functions).

If you abosolutely do not want to have all your functions in a single index.js, you can split the definitions among multiple files, and `require` or `import` them into the main index.js.  It's up to you how you want to organize your source file, using the facilities provided by nodejs and JavaScript.

Comment: but when using the dashboard i can set some parameters that i cant do while deploying through cli... Ex. on dashboard each function can set its own node version, memory alocation, time restriction... etc etc how i do this kind of settings while using a single index.js and thousands of exports

Comment: You can do all that with the Firebase CLI as well.  Just review the documentation. You specify everything in the function definition in code. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions